# Short story about a woman who is changed in to a puma for a month

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, shape-shifter

I read a short story MANY years ago (more than 20).  A woman saves a small fairy-like creature from her cat. The fairy-creature grants her a wish, and she unknowingly asks to be her cat.  Conservation of mass makes her a puma. The spell lasts for a month. She worked in an office-drone type job, with a jerk of a boss. She was about to go on a cruise vacation as when the incident happens (so she's not missed by anyone in her life). She runs across a wildlife biologist type guy, but he thinks she's a wild puma.

She is not in control of the shape-shifting, and it is only temporary. She was described as plump and lacking in self-confidence. If I remember correctly, it was told in first-person, but I might be mistaken.

Comment: Do you think you can pin point a more accurate date, maybe a date of publishing?

Comment: I would say my best guess would be mid-90's when I read it.  I have no idea on when it was actually published.